# Can not connect to MongoDB Atlas in CPanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cpanel, parse-server, mongodb-atlas

When running the app in CPanel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cVLI.png)

I have this error:

> MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.xxx.xx.xxxx:27017

In CPanel dashboard, I[added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaKgZ.png) this IP address to the firewall

In MongoDB Atlass network interface, I [added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDK42.png) the CPanel server ip address:

Here is the complete log:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.xxx.xx.xx:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/c1439621c/nodevenv/my-app-server/14/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:312:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-fgw9tmo-shard-00-00.inp06zb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-fgw9tmo-shard-00-01.inp06zb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-fgw9tmo-shard-00-02.inp06zb.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-109adn-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) You already have a firewall rule that allows the world to connect, so that is not a firewall problem but a potential security problem. 2) The error is **ReplicaSetNoPrimary**. 3) Your replica is not set up correctly, the connection string is incorrectly formatted, etc. Those details are not in your question. 4) Based upon the replica URLs, you are connecting to Atlas, so the problem is with your application.

Comment: @JohnHanley, it works perfectly in local and in Heroku, the problem is with the cpanel host I think

Comment: What works perfectly in local and Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already done whitelisted your cPanel server's IP address in MongoDB Atlas and you are still getting "CONNECTION REFUSED" most likely your cPanel server's Firewall is restricting outgoing connections on port 27017.

If necessary reach out to your hosting provider for that and ask them if 27017 is open for outgoing connections. If they lack technical support, I would highly recommend switching to a managed hosting provider that will help troubleshoot such issues for you and assist you in any Firewall configurations needed.